# Where do the Synaptic Programs Go?

Tags: synaptic

I've been a Linux user all this week and graduated to finding programs in a repository, marking and applying while the system installs. I search everywhere and cannot find anything.

Is there a step by step guide for this?

I don't see how you guys win over MS Windows users... but I'm still trying.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking where packages download to? Are you asking how a package knows where to install which files? Are you asking how dependencies get resolved? What, exactly, do you want to know? Would providing an example help?

Comment: The command `$ dpkg -L [program name]` will print a list with file locations.

Answer (score 0):

Windows scatters bits and pieces of programs all over its filesystem; in %APPSDATA, the Registry, and C:\Program Files\PROGRAMNAME .

Linux is much more consistent, just different. In a terminal window, do `which PROGRAMNAME` substituting the name of your program you are looking for in place of PROGRAMNAME. This finds programs installed by Synaptec, by Ubuntu Programs, by manually installs using `sudo apt install PROGRAMNAME`, and also for preinstalled programs.

Usually you will find programs in **/sbin**, **/usr/sbin**, **/usr/local/bin**, or under **~** AKA **/home/YOURUSERNAME** as a hidden directory.

Once a program is installed, it is added to Ubuntu's menu, or if it's a command-line-only program, you can launch it by typing its name in a terminal window.

Just like with Windows, some programs are so trementously useful that they are built into the Kernel, the heart of the OS. These are things like `ls` (the list files command). However, you can find the basics of how to use them by typing `man PROGRAMNAME` at a shell prompt. aka the Terminal Window.

Also please note that **PROGRAMNAME** is not the same as **ProgramName**, **Programname**, or **programname**, as Linux file naming is case sensitive.